Do I need to populate member id with eg address email?
I am creating a logical model based on the picture I attached. Based on this, do I need to give attributes for example to members? Or can I still create a logical model with just the information attached? I appreciate any help given! Thank you.

Maybe start with a transaction (I'd call it a "loan") table, a member table and a book table?
